# How to solve this Error ::: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE4xP.png)Error only while testing on phone device ,, Working fine in browser.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> /Users/mb/Js/untitled/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
> /Users/mb/Js/untitled/android/app/src/google-services.json
> /Users/mb/Js/untitled/android/app/src/Debug/google-services.json
> /Users/mb/Js/untitled/android/app/google-services.json

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXzY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXzY.png)
```

Comment: Download the google-services.json file which you get while adding the app in your firebase project and add the file in app folder of your project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Switch into the android directory and first call `./gradlew clean`. This gets the android project in flutter to a brand new state. Then go back to your flutter directory and call `flutterfire configure`. This will register your app with the firebase console and sync down all your application keys. Once this is done, you should be able to build like normal. On the first compilation of your app, it will generate a google-services.json file from the API keys within the flutter project.